# Изменить свой голос за закрытие

Tags: поддержка, закрытие-вопросов

Можно ли как-то изменить причину в голосовании за закрытие вопроса?
Предполагал, что если отозвать голос, то можно проголосовать повторно, но нет.

Comment: похоже, что нельзя

Comment: Сегодня столкнулся с этой проблемой. Так как нельзя было изменить причину закрытия, то предположил, что необходимо отозвать голос и повторно проголосовать за закрытие, но не тут-то было. Если бы было какое-либо упоминание о том, что проголосовать повторно невозможно, то я бы оставил некорректную причину, но голос за закрытие бы всё равно бы сохранился. На мой взгляд, не очевидное поведение. Может хотя-бы упомянуть об этом перед отзывом голоса?

Answer (score 4):

Голосовать за закрытие можно только один раз. Иначе перед "протуханием" голоса можно было бы отменить его, а затем снова выставить вопрос на закрытие. Теоретически можно добавить опцию изменения голоса, но я не вижу в этом необходимости.

Голоса за закрытие должны быть основательно продуманными действиями, а не тыканием на первую попавшуюся опцию от балды. Если вам регулярно хочется закрывать-отменять-закрыть-отменять, то вы не слишком внимательно относитесь к голосованию за закрытие. Если же это происходит редко, то об этом не стоит беспокоиться: остальные голоса должны уроавновесить вашу ошибку. Да, иногда случаются ошибки, но это исключительные ситуации, и для этого существуют модераторы.

В целом, невозможность переголосовать тонко вам намекает, что вы должны уделять больше внимания голосам и не беспокоиться из-за мелочей.

Answer (score 1):

Передумал. Хорошая фича. Действительно, это бывает необходимо. Например, когда проголосовал за закрытие, а потом нашел подходящий дубль.

Уверен, что такая фича может быть реализована только для всей сети SE. Поэтому и запрос нужно отправлять на Meta SE. Давайте тут обсудим, а потом отправим?

Comment: Я вам передумаю. См. мой ответ, у вас изначально была верная мысль, что возможны злоупотребления.

Answer (score 1):

Сейчас, пока сайт находится в бете, вопросов мало и постоянно натыкаешься на вопросы, которые уже видел. Но на полноценно функционирующих сайтах недостатка в вопросах нет и процент повторных просмотров вопросов, как мне кажется, гораздо ниже. То есть такая функция может быть полезна только для сайтов в бете. Но меню сайта, насколько я знаю, одинаково для сайтов в бете и вышедних из неё.