# Повторное голосование за закрытие вопроса невозможно?

Tags: поддержка, статус-так-задумано, закрытие-вопросов

Проголосовал за закрытие вопроса как дубликата, потом понял, что указал не тот вопрос, отозвал голос. Попытался проголосовать еще раз, однако диалог закрытия выглядит так -- отсутствует возможность выбирать причину:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Повторное голосование за закрытие запрещено или нужно подождать определенное количество времени?

Comment: Мне казалось, при отзыве голоса об этом предупреждают?..

Comment: Да, совсем нельзя, встроенное ограничение. Скажите, что за вопрос и к чему задубликатить его?

Comment: @NickVolynkin http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/563096/ к http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/539786/. Я сперва задубликатил его, потом понял, что не к тому вопросу, голос отозвал. Нужный вопрос найти не смог, ответил сам, а потом нашел нужный вопрос :).

Comment: @D-side возможно. Я как порядочный юзер предупреждений не читаю :D.

Comment: @andreycha готово.

Comment: @NickVolynkin спасибо.

Comment: Хотел создать такую же тему на мете сегодня, однако нашёл этот вопрос, захотел дать ответ в духе так-и-задумано, но [нашёл похожий вопрос](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1601/213987) с хорошим ответом @Squidward, потому предлагаю к нему и задубликатить.